# How can we translate "we should accept people for what they are"?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-structure

My attempts (I'm not sure of either):

1. Wir sollen Leute für das, was sie sind, akzeptieren
2. Wir sollen Leute dafür, was sie sind, akzeptieren
3. Wir sollen Leute dafür akzeptieren, was sie sind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the above are correct and could be used interchangeably. Additionally, also

> Wir sollen Leute für das akzeptieren, was sie sind.

is possible just as well.

Comment: And it is the most natural one I would say.

Comment: @Emanuel I never heard a sentence like this ("für das ... , was ...). Vogel’s translation ("so akzeptieren, wie sie sind") sounds more familiar.

Comment: This translation is to literal. In German, *für* in context with *akzeptieren* can be only used for its universal meanings, e.g., to indicate the purpose of the acceptance. Therefore »Leute für das akzeptieren, was sie sind« makes as much sense as »Die Gefahr für das erkennen, was sie ist«.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Ich sehe das Problem mit `Die Gefahr für das erkennen, was sie ist.` nicht.

Comment: @Toscho: Die Präposition *für* ergibt in diesem Zusammenhang schlichtweg keinen Sinn bzw. entspricht nicht auch nur im Geringsten dem üblichen Sprachgebrauch. Vielleicht wird dies klarer, wenn man den Nebensatz durch etwas anderes ersetzt, z. B.: »Die Gefahr für groß erkennen«, »Die Gefahr für eine große Bedrohung erkennen.«

Answer (score 5):

Here come my 5 cents:

> Wir sollten Leute so akzeptieren wie sie  sind.

While this translation is not extremely close to the original sentence, I think that all given translations here are "unidiomatic".

This translation focuses more on the meaning behind the sentence and this ends up a little different.

Comment: Your translation is just as idiomatic as the above translations. And the meaning behind the sentence depends on your view on the world. If one likes to categorize people, then the OPs sentence are better suited. If one likes to just describe properties of people without categorizing them, then your sentence is better suited.

Comment: @Toscho that's why there is the *"I think"* and not *"XY states"*